# CallBack вызов

Tags: c#, callback

Как сделать CallBack вызов в C#?

Comment: А что такое callback в вашем понимании? Какой синтаксис вызова вы хотите? А какую семантику? Сколько подписчиков, сколько источников вызова? Опишите свою задачу подробнее.

Comment: Ну передача подпрограммы в качестве параметра другой подпрограммы.
Например в C++:
void do_action(int &x, void(*f)(int &))
{
  f(x);
}

в осн.программе:
int i = 5;
do_action(i, twice);
где twice - функция, удваивающая число
как подобный механизм реализовать в С#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё просто:

C++:

```
void do_action(int &x, void(*f)(int &)) { f(x); }
int i = 5; do_action(i, twice);

void twice(int &x) { x = 2 * x; }
```

C#:

```
public delegate F(ref int x); // как бы typedef
void DoAction(ref int x, F f) { f(ref x); }

void makeDouble(ref int x) { x = 2 * x; }
int i = 5;
DoAction(ref i, makeDouble);
```

Заметьте, что `makeDouble` может быть, в отличие от C++, нестатическим методом (!).

Для нормальных случаев, когда ваш callback не принимает `out`/`ref` аргументов, есть заготовленные делегаты, и практически всегда пользуются именно ими:

```
// Func<int, int> -- функция, принимающая int и возвращающая тоже int
int Apply(int x, Func<int, int> f) { return f(x); }

int getDouble(int x) { return 2 * x; }
int i = 5;
i = Apply(i, getDouble);
```

Или можно проще, с лямбдами:

```
int i = 5;
i = Apply(i, x => 2 * x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Event?

Я могу ошибаться, но я делал примерно так:

```
public class ArtDMXEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public IPAddress Sender;
    public uint      Universe;
    public byte[]    Data;
}

public delegate void ArtDMXHandler(object sender, ArtDMXEventArgs e);

class ArtNetNode
{
    public event ArtDMXHandler onArtDMX;

    // ...

    private void FireOnArtDMX(IPAddress Sender, uint Universe, byte[] Data)
    {
        if (onArtDMX == null) return;

        ArtDMXEventArgs e = new ArtDMXEventArgs();

        e.Sender = Sender;
        e.Data = Data;
        e.Universe = Universe;

        onArtDMX(this, e);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Клиентский код:

```
{
    // Добавление обработчика
    Node.onArtDMX += new ArtDMXHandler(onArtDmx);
}

private void onArtDmx(object Sender, ArtDMXEventArgs e)
{
    // Обработчик, вызывается по приходу пакета
}
```

Все обратные вызовы, насколько я встречал, выполнены по такой механике.